# It's too late for first [impressions]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[impressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/impressions) - 66 questions, no excerpt

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

In most cases, we're talking about advertising impressions, although I have no idea why [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48700624/pass-element-ref-to-a-method-in-angular2) uses the tag

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Most questions are about advertising impressions in various venues, which is off-topic

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

It does, but only in the sense that they identify most as off-topic

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

As I noted in #1, mostly it does, but not in all cases.

Comment: And only one question with only that tag: makes clean-up a bit easier, I guess.